# Powershell scheduled job will not start

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The new scheduled jobs in powershell 3 look fantastic, but to my horror I am unable to get them to work.

```
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath V:\scripts\testJob.ps1 -Name Test
$t = New-JobTrigger -At 6PM -Once
Add-JobTrigger -Trigger $t -Name Test
```

I never see any errors or anything but the script doesn't execute. If I open up task scheduler I can see the job and it says it "ran". But in History there is an 'Action Completed' with

```
Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\Test" , instance "{a117256e-c3f2-42a7-a290-f21aeb6b2260}" , action "StartPowerShellJob" with return code 1.
```

I've tried futzing with the scheduled task in task scheduler but haven't gotten anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas?

The script just looks like this:

```
$path = "C:\temp\jobbit.log"
Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $path -Append
```

Comment: Have you verified that your script runs when called manually? What does the script do? Dies it require admin privileges to run?

Comment: Is there anything in the job buffer history?  If the job ran at all there should be a job object left behind.  You can use receive-job to see if there's anything in the output buffers.

Comment: Just don't forget to Import-Module PSScheduledJob in order to hook the scheduled job provider into the jobs infrastructure. Otherwise, Get-Job won't show scheduled jobs.

Comment: The script looks like this:
Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\jobbit.log" -Append;
Manually it runs fine. I've tried setting the task to run elevated.
If I do get-job (after ipmo psschedulejob) it does not show anything.

Comment: Is there anything in the Powershell or Security Event logs that lines up with the job start events?

Comment: @mjolinor Yes there is. "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'V' does not exist". I put my script on a mapped network drive, apparently PS doesn't like that.

Comment: Most likely that drive mapping does not exist in the environment you're trying to run the script in.  Does it work if you creat V: using  new-psdrive in the script so that drive reference will resolve?

Comment: ?The script doesn't get called so there is no chance to set the drive. Anyway I tried using the UNC path and it still can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using the Task Scheduler itself to run a PowerShell script. The way I finally got it to work was to invoke PowerShell directly and pass the script I wanted to run as an argument

In your case if I understand the cmdlet syntax correctly, it would be:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name Test
-FilePath C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
-ArgumentList ("-NonInteractive","C:\scripts\testJob.ps1")
```

I assume the runtime environment of the scheduled task simply does not automatically run ps1 files with PowerShell.

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax is incorrect. The `FilePath` parameter has to point to a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to revive an old thread, but for those searching around for an answer...

I had the same issue on Windows Server 2012 R2. The solution was simple and infuriating at the same time.

All I had to do was drop '.exe' from "Program/script". That's it. It should be:

```
powershell
```

and not

```
powershell.exe
```

This of course is without seeing the rest of your command arguments. I have no clue why this worked.

Comment: Interesting that this made a difference. I don't think I ever messed with the command arguments since register-scheduledjob sets all that up for you automatically. I did get this working for me; if I remember correctly it had something to do with running as the logged-in user.